# Java: calling super.clone() method, volatile int value not copied in cloned object

Tags: java, copy, int, clone, volatile

I faced one production bug (it happened only once at least in last 1 year). After investigation I can conclude that **super.clone() method was unable to copy an "volatile int" value to the new cloned object**.

Does anyone faced this problem ever?

clone() method is widely used in jdk libraries and this is a basic thing that clone method guarantees. Can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe to clone volatile data. Please see this [post](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/class/avoid-side-effects-with-object-clone/) for side effects of cloning.

Comment: The example taken in the "post" provided doesn't tell about problem with volatile.
When you clone, object's reference is copied and primitive's value is copied. In the example given, cloned object is pointing to the same Date object, but int value is copied locally. I can't see any problem.